# AngularJS 1.3 - Datepicker initial format is incorrect

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I started using AngularJS 1.3 yesterday and one problem I have found is that the initial date in the Datepicker is not in the defined format. The format of the date is correct *after* choosing a date.

The initial format is correct with AngularJS 1.2.10 as can be seen in the example by commenting out the script tag.

How can I set the initial format to be correct?

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/lPmgnz5hqzsV1HiTlX9Z?p=preview)

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script> -->
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

  <br>
  <br>
  <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("DatepickerDemoCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.format = 'dd-MMMM-yyyy';

  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not sure exactly what changed in 1.3, but there is a [bug report for this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2659).

Here's a drop-in directive for the initial value that fixes the problem until the bug is fixed. And here is a demo [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gM5DvVSSy5mWULUPp8nN?p=preview).

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('datepickerPopup', function (dateFilter, datepickerPopupConfig) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
            var dateFormat = attr.datepickerPopup || datepickerPopupConfig.datepickerPopup;
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return dateFilter(value, dateFormat);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
app.controller("DatepickerDemoCtrl", function ($scope,$filter) { .. // $filter added
```

```
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = $filter('date')(new Date(), $scope.format);
};
```

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" ... // {{format}} added
```

Please check with these three modifications.

Comment: it not work if change $scope.dt from another function
$scope.prevDate = function () {
        var oldDate = angular.copy($scope.dt);
        $scope.dt = new Date( oldDate.setDate( oldDate.getDate() + 1 ) );
    }

Comment: Sorry, I have now marked davetjohnson's answer as the correct fix. Your solution was causing other problems (maybe the same as that pointed out by ahiipsa).